# Create a movie from STL file?

Tags: computer-aided-design, solidworks

After finish designing a product and having some `STL` files, I would like to make some movie of it, and animate it .

For example same as Apple does in its marketing videos, where you see the product zoomed in and camera covering it from many directions.

So, `Solidworks` can't do that, is there other software that can do that ?

Comment: Resource recommendation questions are not within the scope of this site. Since this has to do with software, you can try asking at [softwarerecs.SE].

Answer (score 2):

Almost any 3D CAD programs can make movies.  How detailed you want the movies, various textures (i.e. "shiny metal"), etc... is where the devil resides.  As long as your software will render the material properly to your satisfaction, and you are proficient in the software, it should make a movie and you should use it.